# How to a show a block between two points in highchart

Tags: highcharts

I have to implement a feature which is to show a bar from A to B in highchart.
What I want to do is to for any two given points, I need to add a red bar. 
For example: show a red bar between A(10:25) to B(10:35).

I failed to find any answer online, does anybody know how to do that? Thanks.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found arearange can solve the problem.